# What is the public flag for on custom Field sets?

Tags: custom-fields

What is the public flag for on custom Field sets?
It seems that even if a field is marked as public, it will not show up for anonymous users on a profile unless I give anonymous users the "access all custom data" permission.
What is the public flag for?

Answer (score 1):

From https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/#is-this-custom-field-set-public

> Is this Custom Field Set public?
>   If a custom field set is marked as public, its fields will be shown on public-facing pages.
>
> For example, custom fields that should be shown on an event information page should belong to a field set marked as public. Custom fields that relate to administrative information about an event should be part of a field set that is not be marked as public.
>
> Note that the setting is at the Custom Field Set level and applies to all Custom Fields in the Set. Individual fields cannot be marked as public or not.

Comment: I Marked a field set as public and the field does not show up on front facing forms... Bug?

Comment: what sort of entity? can you replicate on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

Comment: It's a contact field.

Comment: can you replicate on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org?

Comment: https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/profile/create?gid=17&reset=1 both public and not public are visible. I'm assuming the permission is given to anonymous to access all custom data. Can't really test there because I cannot access permissions

Comment: This does not relate to permissions - fields marked as not public should not show on public-facing pages regardless of permissions.  This is a fairly new feature and I recall seeing a note somewhere (but forget where) that this was not fully implemented.  It does work for custom fields on events as in the documentation but may not work fully elsewhere.  Looking at the implementation for events would give clues for extending this if you want a holiday project :-)

Comment: @aiden, It has to do with permissions because I cannot show a custom field on a profile form unless I grant anonymous the "access all custom data" permission. Regardless of whether the field is flagged as public or not. In other words, My only choice is that either all custom fields are visible or none are

Answer (score 1):

The way to expose a custom field on a public profile form is by using ACL permissions.

Administer>Users and Permissions> Permissions
Select "Manage ACLs"
Add ACL
Role=Everyone
Operation=Edit
Type of Data=A set of custom data fields
Save

The public flag is doesn't do anything when it comes to displaying the custom fields on a public profile form.